# Is the completion of a local ring local?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $m$ and let $I\subset m$. Is the $I$-adic completion of $A$ necessarily local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the proof goes like I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263476/121097).

But a more general result holds: the $I$-adic completion $\widehat R$ is quasi-local iff $R/I$ is quasi-local. (Quasi-local means local, but not necessarily noetherian.) See [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supFormal.pdf) on page $6$.